# Get colors using Mac OS X terminal when editing source code in remote linux machines

Tags: vim, macos

I use terminal from Mac OS X Leopard to connect to remote Linux machines and edit C++ code there using VI.

What determines that in some machines, using the same MACOSX terminal settings, the source code gets colorized and in other not?

Thanks

Comment: This is a question about termcap configuration, and is more suitable for superuser.com. However, it is too vague to be answerable in its current form. You will have to provide more details as to what is working and what is not working, and read up about terminal configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you used `:syntax enable` in vim on the remote machine? Just asking, since on the ones that are working it could be in `.vimrc` or similar.

Comment: PERFECT! Saved me eye bleeding

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the `$TERM` environment variable determines whether the terminal is capable of color.

`$TERM` is set upon connection to the remote terminal. From there, you can try `export TERM='xterm-color'` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the .vimrc with

set term=xterm-color

worked for me in OS X tiger server. I put this at the top of the .vimrc. I also set the term app on OS X El capitan host to xterm in the preferences. I have syntax highlighting over ssh. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, these "remote linux machines" usually have a 'small' or 'tiny' version of vim installed which does not have syntax highlighting. When in vim, enter the command `:version`, and see if you have `+syntax` or `-syntax` in the feature list. If you don't have `+syntax`, then vim has been compiled without syntax support and you need to recompile vim on that machine.